# reading varbinary from MySQL - or hiding sensitive information from the console

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, aes, varbinary

I have a field that holds an AES_ENCRYPT value in MySQL. I'm using `varbinary` as the field type.
I need to pass this value to JavaScript
(this field contains emails of users - which I do not want them to be readable from the console)

so I wanted the encrypted value.
the only way I seem to be able to read the value is with AES_DECODE(email, salt).

how can i read this value in its original decoded form - so I will be able to pass it via XHR to DOM.

if remembering the goal set on my first paragraph - perhaps I'm doing this the wrong way - any simpler suggestion will be more then welcome as well :-)

Thank you

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the response from your request, please? Do you get `null` from `json_decode`?

Comment: @GustavoStraube - I did not use json_decode in my php script - tried that now. does not work :-) - the problem seems to be with the binary data only

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant `json_encode`. That in the end of your PHP script.

Comment: @GustavoStraube - sorry my problem seems to lie elsewhere - in trying to read varbinary without decoding it from MySQL - I simply need the binary field to be encoded so it will not be viewed from the console after pass it to javascript - I will change my question